# Error with Generics with clousers i.e. '(Any) -> Void' is not convertible to '(T) -> Void

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Generics with `@escaping closure` but getting error on `completion(JSON)` as -

> '(Any) -> Void' is not convertible to '(T) -> Void'

Below is my tried code

```
static func getData<T>(inputUrl:String,parameters:[String:Any],completion:@escaping(_: T)->Void){
        let url = URL(string: inputUrl)
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

            let nilValue = ""
            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                completion(JSON)
            }
            else {
                completion(nilValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the generic type, `T` anywhere in your code and you just return a value of type `Any` regardless of the type of `T`.

If you really want your function to be generic, you should cast `response.result.value` to T and return that value in the completion handler. Moreover, don't return an empty String in case of failure, make the closure accept an optional and return `nil` in case of failure.

```
static func getData<T>(inputUrl:String,parameters:[String:Any],completion:@escaping(_: T?)->Void){
    let url = URL(string: inputUrl)
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value as? T {
            completion(json)
        }
        else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do we really need type casting `as? T` , I believe that Generics is used for type safety, Anything that we can improve above snippet ?

Comment: Yes, you need the casting, since `response.result.value` has type `Any`, which is not an exact type. Due to the `as?`, the casting __is safe__. This code snippet provides type safety, while your code didn't, since instead of actually using the generic type parameter, you just masked the exact type using `Any`.